# Deserialize and serialize Json data in Winform

Tags: json, vb.net, visual-studio-2017, json.net

I have a winform with a combobox and some textboxes. I get the Json data via REST API and deserialize it via Json.NET and a class file.

**The JsonHelper**

```
   Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Public Module JsonHelper

    Public Function FromClass(Of T)(data As T, Optional isEmptyToNull As Boolean = False, Optional jsonSettings As JsonSerializerSettings = Nothing) As String

        Dim response As String = String.Empty

        If Not EqualityComparer(Of T).Default.Equals(data, Nothing) Then
            response = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data, jsonSettings)
        End If

        Return If(isEmptyToNull, (If(response = "{}", "null", response)), response)

    End Function

    Public Function ToClass(Of T)(data As String, Optional jsonSettings As JsonSerializerSettings = Nothing) As T
        Dim response = Nothing

        If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(data) Then
            response = If(jsonSettings Is Nothing,
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of T)(data),
                JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Of T)(data, jsonSettings))
        End If

        Return response

    End Function

End Module

    Imports Newtonsoft.Json

Namespace Models

    Public Class Header

        <JsonProperty("Name")>
        Public Property Name As String

        <JsonProperty("DisplayAt")>
        Public Property DisplayAt As String
    End Class
```

**The Class file**

```
    Public Class DataSource

        <JsonProperty("Id")>
        Public Property Id As String

        <JsonProperty("Name")>
        Public Property Name As String

        <JsonProperty("Headers")>
        Public Property Headers As Header()

        <JsonProperty("Rows")>
        Public Property Rows As String()()

        <JsonProperty("TotalRows")>
        Public Property TotalRows As Integer

        <JsonProperty("LastUpdated")>
        Public Property LastUpdated As DateTime

        <JsonProperty("CompanyId")>
        Public Property CompanyId As Integer
    End Class

    Public Class Category

        <JsonProperty("DataSource")>
        Public Property DataSource As DataSource
    End Class

End Namespace
```

The combobox is populated with data from the Json file and via bindingsource the textboxes are connected to the combobox. So if you select another row, the values of the textboxes change.

**The bindingsource**

```
Dim bindingSource As BindingSource = New BindingSource()
        bindingSource.DataSource = dt
        bindingSource.Sort = "Weergave DESC"
        ListBox1.DataSource = bindingSource

        ListBox1.DisplayMember = "Weergave"
        ListBox1.ValueMember = "Id"
        'ListBox1.Sorted = True

        txtWeergave.DataBindings.Clear()
        txtWeergave.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ListBox1.DataSource, "Weergave", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
        txtProjectnaam.DataBindings.Clear()
        txtProjectnaam.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ListBox1.DataSource, "Projectnaam", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
        txtProjectnummer.DataBindings.Clear()
        txtProjectnummer.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ListBox1.DataSource, "Projectnummer", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
        txtServicemonteur.DataBindings.Clear()
        txtServicemonteur.DataBindings.Add(New Binding("Text", ListBox1.DataSource, "Servicemonteur", True, DataSourceUpdateMode.OnPropertyChanged))
```

I wan't to make some changes to the data and update the database via a PUT request.
Therefore I made the following routine:

```
    Private Sub PutData()
    Dim request As WebRequest = WebRequest.Create("my url")
    request.ContentType = "application/json"
    request.Method = "PUT"
    ' Get the response.
    Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
    ' Get the stream containing content returned by the server.
    Dim dataStream As Stream = response.GetResponseStream()
    ' Open the stream using a StreamReader for easy access.
    Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
    ' Read the content.
    Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
    'Dim JObject As Object


    Dim rawJson As String = responseFromServer

    Dim dataSource As String = JsonHelper.FromClass(Of Category)(rawJson).DataSource

End Sub
```

The following things are not clear for me.
If I make changes in the textbox, the changes are also made in the combobox because they have been connected with eachother via a bindingsource. But does the values also change in the Class file?

How can I make changes to the values of the textboxes and update the datasource via a PUT request?

Answer (score 0):

It's not completely clear becacuse some things are missing from your question, such as your binding configuration, but..

Generally I wouldn't expect things to be that "when I change the textbox the combo will change". Let's take some artificial example of a Person class with Name and Ethnicity. Name is a string and would be bound to a textbox. Ethnicity is a fixed list of values, and I would expect a combo to be bound up such that the combo's datasource, displaymember and valuememeber related to the columns/properties of a list of ethnicities, and then the combo's selectedvalue be bound to the person's ethnicity setting. This way changing the selected item in the combo edits their ethnicity to one of the other values in the fixed list of ethnicities. Changing the value displayed in the name box doesn't change anything about the ethnicity. If you have a list of multiple Person that the bindingsource is managing, then you can navigate the bindingsource to show different people and edit them. It's probably easiest to see if you also add a datagridview, albeit temporarily, bound to the same bindingsource that persons are bound through; changing the current row of the grid navigates the bindingsource and the textbox/combobox will change to show the details for the new person

The PUT request is easier to answer; you formulate a block of json for the server to work on by re-serializing your edited class to JSON, and then send it as the body of the put request

```
request.Method = "PUT"

'formulate a body
Dim postData = JsonHelper.FromClass(editedPerson)

Dim encoding As New ASCIIEncoding() 'or whatever
Dim byte1 As Byte() = encoding.GetBytes(postData)

request.ContentType = "application/json"
request.ContentLength = byte1.Length
Dim reqStream = request.GetRequestStream()
reqStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length)
reqStream.Close()


' Get the response.
Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

---

By the way, in C# at least, you can right click your project name and choose Add REST Client, give it the URL of the swagger/openapi descriptor of your web service and it will make all the client classes for you which can simplify interaction a lot. Though it's a C# only thing (it's based on autorest which I don't think supports VB), C# and VB are the same thing internally, so you can add a C# project alongside your VB one purely for purposes of creating a rest client, and then import a reference to the c# project into your VB one

Comment: Thank you for your response Caius Jard.I added the boundingsource too the quesion. I have populated the combobox with a datatable witch was created from the Json. But my question is how do I populate all the textfields that where changed to Json and update my databasy via a PUT request.

Comment: Oh, I see the confusion now. 1- you don't have a combobox, you have a listbox; different things. 2- your textboxes are bound to the same bindingsource that the list box is; it would be less confusing if you bind your textboxes to `bindingsource` rather than `listbox1.DataSource`

Comment: Sorry, my mistake :-)

Comment: *my question is how do I populate all the textfields* - You don't populate the textboxes; binding does that. You should see a value in the textbox automatically. If you change the value it is stored back in the model (you've called it dataSource as far as I can tell; a fairly nondescript name btw- it would be better as Person, Order, Employee etc rather that Info, Data, Object, Array etc) automatically. You retrieve the model value that you want to send to the server and send it. If the server accepts multiples, you can send a collection. If it accepts singles you send one by one